# Anaconda Navigator stuck at "loading user" (MacOS)

Tags: python, anaconda

So I've been trying to launch Anaconda for a couple of hours now, and it keeps getting stuck at "loading user".

I uninstalled and reinstalling both Python and Anaconda. Tried launching it via the terminal, no luck. The green logo appears first with "initializing", then "loading user" and that's where it gets stuck. The longest I've waited was 15 mins. The Anaconda troubleshooting site wasn't helpful either. Other discussions are about getting stuck at loading applications inside Anaconda, or getting specific errors, but that's not my case. How do I fix it?

EDIT: It worked just fine (albeit slow) until a few days ago. I didn't update my OS or anything.